# Network device can be pinged but no tcp connection

Tags: c#, networking, windows-7, tcp, tcpclient

I have built a windows service, that connects to a local network device via tcpClient, using an IP and a portnumber. The network device streams out data, that i receive an read. That has been working for MONTHS for multiple setups (Always 1 machine->1 network device).

Now recently almost all the connection-attempts started failing!
The weired thing is, that i can still ping the device via command prompt.
In putty, no data is transferred.
With netstat i didn't see any remote-adress listed.

In my service there is the following error-log message:

```
 Exception by Establishing TCP/IP Connection@ServiceName System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX  (translated into english ;D)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
```

Is this network-related? Or has it to do with windows-updates or anything?

My up-to-recently working code

```
  public void readDevice()
        {

            TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IP"]);

                /*
                * Establishing TCP/IP Connection
                */
                try
                {
                    // IP and Port number  
                    log.Debug("Try Client.Connect:" + ip);
                    Client.Connect(ip, 5000);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    /* Handle the socket exception.... */
                   //this error is thrown
                    log.Debug("Exception by Establishing TCP/IP Connection@ServiceName "+ ex);
                }

                NetworkStream MessageStream = Client.GetStream();

      //Magic be here

        }
```

I am really stuck, because of the ping-able but not connectable device.
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: At first glance it sounds like a firewall problem, can you connect to the port with telnet?

Comment: While both "ping" and TCP connections ultimately uses the IP protocol, they are often handled differently. It's not uncommon for a firewall to let ping messages through but stop other kind of traffic.

Comment: have you changed any ip address recently, like default gateway..? what kind of topology is your network ?

Comment: no changes in IP address, no changed gateway. Its a standard home network, where both devices connect via LAN. No connection via telnet possible @GeraldSchneider . As described further down: Do i even need to open a port in the router for LAN-Communication?? I cannot remember having done this when this used to work...

Comment: I am controlling these devices and machines via remote-desktop, and dont like to bother the households too much about technology-problems. Turns out: just disconnecting and reconnecting the network device fixed it. mfw o0, thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much help this will be, but it sounds like a network problem.  If it just stopped working and nothing has changed code wise, I would start investigating there.

I had an issue like this with a server of mine, and the problem ended up being that the port forwarding tables got messed up so I was trying to connect to the wrong machine.  I just fixed the forwarding, and blam-o! Everything worked great.

I hope your problem is as easy to solve.

Comment: I really dont get it. I cannot seem to be able to open this port. On the other hand: These are both local network devices connected via LAN and a stanard home-router - is it even neccessary to open ports for them in the router, when only communicating within the LAN?

Comment: @Timo Jak: Yes, sometime you have to make sure the data on a port is going to the right machine, even on your lan.  You could grab a copy of wireshark or other port sniffer and see if it is open on the target machine.  That may yield a a-ha! moment.